# How to add new array value to header in php

Tags: php, api, http-headers, postman

This is my **test_b.php** file:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $url = 'http://my_url/test_b.php';
  $x = get_headers($url, 1);
  print_r($x);
}
```

I am getting output in postman like this:
[image]

I want to add another parameter in the header *after **[Content-Type]*** like ***[Authkey]***

I am new in API development. Can anybody help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice job covering your URL in the image and then posting it in your code. What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: Thank you for informing. I forgot to change url. LOL.

Comment: There's `header` function in php. Googling will tell you about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
header('Authkey: your key');
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $url = 'http://localhost/jobs/ZikraBytes/starshow/test_b.php';
    $x =get_headers($url, 1);
    print_r($x);
}
```